# the error message in die() function is not getting displayed

Tags: php

```
$mysqli=new mysqli(HOSTNAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD,"NoSuchDatabase") OR die("cannot connect");
```

when I try to connect with the server using the above code by a providing a wrong database name the die function Is not getting executed and a error is thrown stating no such database found...my problem Is I just want the message In the die function to be displayed "cannot connect" and hide the error

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
$connect=mysqli_connect(HOSTNAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD) OR die("cannot connect");
```

..then try with a wrong password.